# ESP 32 AsyncWebServer download a .txt file?

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, webserver, esp32

I work with the ESP32, I use an AsyncWebServer, at some point I have to press a button on the html interface to save data in a file named `test.txt`, and download this file automatically at the end of save on browser.

I've tried using the code below. The button works, save function works, but the obtained file is not downloaded to browser at the end.

What can I do to solve this issue?

```cpp
server.on("/download", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    Serial.println("Url /download executed...");
    saveValues();  // function to save values to `test.txt` file
    request->send(SPIFFS, "/test.txt", "text/plain", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a response object with `request->beginResponse()` which in turn generates an [AsyncFileResponse](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer/blob/master/src/WebRequest.cpp#L733-L743) instance, which will set the correct http headers (such as "Content-Disposition", "Content-Encoding") for file downloading.

I have not tested the code, but this will be the general direction on what you need for your code:

```cpp
server.on("/download", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  Serial.println("Url /download executed...");
  saveValues();  // function to save values to `test.txt` file
  AsyncWebServerResponse *response = request->beginResponse(SPIFFS, "/test.txt", "text/plain", true);
  request->send(response);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it, it compilate correctely, but it does not work.

Comment: How is your HTML setup for the download? and what does your `saveValues()` do? Maybe you should update your question and provide information about html page and your code in handling the download request.